# Web Assembly not compiling with linker error [Uno Platform]

Tags: c#, webassembly, uno-platform

So, I have been trying to compile a project in web assembly with Uno Platform, but I have not been able to successfully compile due to a linker error, This error is something like this:

```
Fatal error in Mono IL Linker

Mono.Linker.MarkException: Error processing method: 'System.Void Microsoft.Xaml.Interactivity.Behavior::.cctor()' in assembly: 'Microsoft.Xaml.Interactivity.dll' ---> Mono.Cecil.ResolutionException: Failed to resolve Uno.Diagnostics.Eventing.IEventProvider Uno.Diagnostics.Eventing.Tracing::Get(System.Guid)
```

I thought that maybe the Uno.Diagnostics.Eventing was missing or something, so, I've installed but after doing that the error persists.
I don't know what the error could be or if it is related to something else, anyone can give a hand?

Answer (score 1):

Well, it seems that for my specific version of Uno.WebAssembly (3.0.17) I needed the package Uno.Microsoft.Xaml.Behaviors.Uwp.Managed to be on version 2.0.2-uno.79 to work. Simple as that